# Altering a query to show the overall sum of the numbers combined

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering if there was a way to alter the below query to show the overall results

```
SELECT STATUS ,count( * )
FROM vicidial_list
WHERE list_id
BETWEEN 2732900  AND 2732905
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

This is what it currently shows

```
STATUS  count( * )
A   32
AA  1386
ADC 57
B   21
DNC 50
DROP    70
LR  21
N   36
NA  319
NC  38
NL  7
PDROP   6
R   45
RD  1136
RO  506
SALE    102
TP  3
WN  6
```

Is there a way to alter the query to show the sum of just the A, AA, B, Drop, N, NA, NC, and PDROP so when I run the query it will just give me all these status codes added up?

What I would like to show

```
STATUS  count( * )
A   32
AA  1386
B   21
DROP    70
N   36
NA  319
NC  38
PDROP   6
```

Total = 1908 **The overall sum of these status codes are most important**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this :

```
SELECT status
      ,count(*) counts
FROM vicidial_list
WHERE list_id BETWEEN 2732900 AND 2732905
and status in ('A', 'AA', 'B', 'Drop', 'N', 'NA', 'NC', 'PDROP') 
GROUP BY status with rollup
ORDER BY 1
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=baf3aa0527419299935e02228477be6e)*

Comment: When using the query you provided, it seems like it did the opposite and showed the other status codes


case when status in ('A', 'AA', 'B', 'Drop', 'N', 'NA', 'NC', 'PDROP') then 'group 1' else status end count( * )
AR 1
COV19 1
DC 24
DNC 11
DNCL 8
ERI 2
group 1 554
LR 3
NL 6
NQ 2
R 21
RD 145
SALE 11
TP 4

Comment: @Kyle show us what's your expected result

Comment: I edited my post with more information. I would like the query to autosum only status codes 'A', 'AA', 'B', 'Drop', 'N', 'NA', 'NC', 'PDROP'

Comment: @Kyle see updated answer

Comment: yes! that is a lot better! Is there away to add to the query where it will have all those status codes added up? So if there are 10 As and 10 NAs, the end result will show 20 overall? Basically, I would like the query to add all the numbers up for me so I do not have to use a calculator if possible

Comment: @Kyle this is producing what you shows as desired output , isn't it?

Comment: yes it is showing the desired output for the most part, but ideally, I would rather have the sum of all those status codes combined.
A 20
AA 30
Total 30 <------- this is the most important part

Comment: @Kyle see updated answer

Comment: the updated query is failing. When running that query, this is the error I am getting "Query to show fields from table failed"

Comment: @Kyle that's not from database , maybe give the count(*) column a name as well

Comment: Still getting that same error message. I am going to play around with it more and see what happens. I tried the Sum feature but that seems to also not work  :(

Comment: the query itself is working perfectly , see *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=baf3aa0527419299935e02228477be6e)*

Comment: you are correct, the query does work. It is just not working on our database for some reason. I really do appreciate your help. I will continue to troubleshoot to find a workaround :)